# In SDL, how do I move a rectangle without clearing screen?

Tags: c++, sdl

If I draw a rectangle, and render it to the screen, then change the position of the rectangle, and render it to the screen, it draws two rectangles: the previous one is still there.

I could clear the window in-between these two actions, but that seems a bit silly. Imagine having a million points and only needing to move one of them. Would I then have to redraw the entire image again?

How do I just move ONE object? From x,y to x+1, y+1 say?

Comment: treat it as a sprite? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48087300/rendering-sprites-with-sdl2

Comment: Modern graphics cards and APIs are optimized for the clear/draw/display cycle. It's what they are good at. Just embrace it. Clear the screen every frame, draw everything, then display the result.